# mouseenter and mouseleave with jquery

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseleave

i want to use this for 2 pictures.On mouseEnter, changes to img2, on mouseLeave the first image becomes visible again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    onenter 
        SlideShow.SetVisible("#img1", true);
        SlideShow.Play("#img2");
    onleave 
        SlideShow.SetVisible("#img1", false);
});
```

I guess I'm doing things wrong here...

Comment: What exactly is not working? Any errors?

Comment: animation not working..no errors from what i can see